# What is best practice for javascript import?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, web-frontend

Ok, lets think we are making a wordpress theme. We have a lot of javascript module like sliders or carousels or ajax loading elements or form controls etc. My main approach for this put the all javascript codes into the main.js files. In main.js i have a code something like this;

```
$(".slider").startSlider();
```

And i import main.js to all pages. So if one of the pages has element which is class is "slider" they work perfectly. But i am curious about this is the true approach or not? If you not use any javascript module in your page still all javascript codes importing your page. Do you have any different approach?

Comment: put it in `header` OR `footer`

Comment: There isn't one true way. You're either loading JS on pages that don't need it (which costs CPU and bandwidth (which can be offset by caching)) or your adding an extra HTTP request for pages that do need it while making your code more complicated since you end up with additional script elements to keep track of.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
if ($(".slider").length>0) { 
  jQuery.getScript("slider.js")
    .done(function() {
      $(".slider").startSlider();
  });
}
```

Comment: It seems like more proper way because you check if has slider, but do you know this is more fast than just writing '$(".slider").startSlider();' or not? It seems like slower.

Comment: If slider.js is already loaded, then yes it is of course faster to just start it. However all other pages will also load slider.js in that case

Answer (score -1):

You really need to get familiar with how `wp_enqueue_script()` works so you can add scripts from within your theme functions on an as needed basis.

For your slider example you can then add the needed scripts from within template functions or shortcode functions

Reference : [wp_enqueue_script docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

Comment: @mplungjan was wondering same thing since this is a wordpress best practice approach to script management

Comment: I can imagine. I do not do WP so I gave just a jQuery alternative -which also got voted down btw

Comment: Firstly, I am curious about your words is it way for wordpress something like that: if used this shortcode import this javascript file. Secondly, this is not wordpress spesific question, it is just example. I want to understand approach/doing way more than just getting code. So i can make the approach both wordpress and custom php scripts.

Comment: Well my answer was certainly wordpress specific since that was mentioned in question and tags. Over the years there were too many script collisions and duplications which is why a solid script manager was implemented